# How often are sales stats updated on iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My app was accepted by Apple today and I am trying to figure out how many times it has been downloaded. Does anybody know how often the sales stats are updated on iTunes Connect? Is it once per day? If so, at what time is it updated?

Comment: Congrats on releasing your first app! I recommend you try appFigures.com -- they have a great 14-day trial of their premium features, which includes emailing you a report around 4AM PST of your day's sales (the free one works fine, especially if you don't have a ton of apps). I don't have anything to do with the company, btw, I just wanted to share this. :)

Comment: They're not always consistent and sometimes are really delayed so we @ [Appfigures](https://appfigures.com) created a report for it :) http://appfigures.com/itcstatus

Comment: @Ariel The new URL is https://appfigures.com/store-status/app-store-connect

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to Page 17 of [Apple's latest documentation](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf),

> Reports are available by 6 a.m. in each territory’s respective time zone.

In the US, this would be PST. In Europe, Africa, and Asia, this is in CET. In Japan, it is JST. And in Australia and New Zealand this would be in AEST.

Comment: Except, it rarely is. :) Better odds of hitting it big on the roulette table than reliably getting reports by 6am in each territory.

Answer (score 49):

Around 3am ~ 5am PST daily when the system is working normally has been my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Normal time is : 9:00 a.m. Pacific Time (PT).

See [Apple latest document](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for providing documentation supporting your answer. I've never seen that before but maybe the document is really new.

Comment: That is a 404 now 