# App Store Connect: where is in-app purchases statistics?

Tags: statistics, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

In which section of the App Store Connect can I see statistics about in-app purchases and subscriptions? How often is this information updated?

I have a free app with the ability to make in-app purchases. I need to find out when and which in-app purchase was completed (preferably with grouping by country).

Answer (score 0):

On AppStoreConnect in App Analytics tab you can check statistics.

> And add filter and choose country or Region

I am not sure but as per following thread, you can check how often Apple updates statistics!

[How often are sales stats updated on iTunes Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567770/how-often-are-sales-stats-updated-on-itunes-connect)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. I truly understand that this information is not updated instantly, but with a delay of 72 hours?

Comment: I've edited my answer, and shared a link from where you can get more information regarding this! FYI - I am not so sure about this though. :)